# Webpack adding ".default" to Dexie Plugin import

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, dexie

I'm using Dexie, and am trying to use the `dexie-relationships` addon (https://github.com/ignasbernotas/dexie-relationships). However, after including it, and trying to use it, webpack adds a `.default` to it, which results in an error as there is no `.default` on the module.

**Code:**

```
import Dexie from 'dexie';
import relationships from 'dexie-relationships'

export class AppDatabase extends Dexie {

    constructor(){
        super('AppDatabase', {addons: [relationships]});
    }
}
```

**What webpack outputs:**

```
const dexie_1 = __webpack_require__(30);
const dexie_relationships_1 = __webpack_require__(57);
class AppDatabase extends dexie_1.default {
    constructor() {
        super('AppDatabase', { addons: [dexie_relationships_1.default] });
    }
}
```

The `dexie_relationships_1.default` doesn't work as `dexie_relationships_1` is the function that's supposed to be passed.

Why is it doing this, and what can I do to correct this behavior?